# Measure of alignment between a vector and a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Edit: I've thought better of my question, which is quite ill-posed, but I will keep it open to [avoid deleting it](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question).

Given a complex vector $u$ and a complex square matrix $V$ with eigenvectors $v_i$, I would like to define a 'total alignment' $(u, V) \in \mathbb{R}^{+}$ to be the modulus of the product of inner products:
$$ (u, V) = \left\lvert \prod_i (u \cdot v_i) \right\rvert \,. $$
Unfortunately, this definition seems to depend on the choice of eigenvectors $v_i$. How can I define it in such a way that it is independent? I tried using determinants, but haven't made much progress. If it makes anything easier, feel free to assume that $u, V$ are real, and that $V$ is unitary.

Motivation: I'm working on a research problem and would like some way to describe how close a given vector $u$ is to being an eigenvector of $V$.

Comment: What is 'alignment'? Can I fix this by saying $(u, V)=0$? Also, how does a product of dot products have a norm (is it modulus)?

Comment: Alignment is what I defined it to be. A product of complex dot products is a complex number, so has a norm (a modulus).

Comment: If you're looking for a way to describe how close $u$ is to being an eigenvector of $V$, perhaps the best thing to look at is the angle between the vectors $u$ and $Vu$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an alternative metric: in general, we can define $f(u,V)$ to be $1$ whenever $Vu = 0$, and otherwise define
$$
f(u,V) = 
\frac{|u \cdot (Vu)|}{\|u\| \, \|Vu\|}.
$$
$f(u,V)$ measures the alignment between $u$ and $Vu$ by giving the cosine of the acute angle between the lines spanned by the two vectors. $f$ will be $1$ in the case that $u$ is an eigenvector of $V$ and $0$ in the case that $u$ is orthogonal to $Vu$.

If it is known that $V$ is unitary, this expression can be simplified to
$$
f(u,V) = \frac{|u \cdot Vu|}{|u \cdot u|}.
$$

Comment: Thanks Ben. Unfortunately I'm really looking to have a product of dot products, whereas $u \cdot Vu$ is rather more like a sum. In other words, I want the alignment to be zero if $u$ is orthogonal to *any* eigenvector of $V$, not if $u$ is orthogonal to $Vu$.

Comment: @smalldog That seems a bit nonsensical. For one thing, a unitary $V$ will have an orthonormal set of eigenvectors; so by your definition, if $u$ is an eigenvector of $V$, then the alignment will be zero.

Comment: @smalldog For example, with 
$$
V = \pmatrix{1 & 0\\0 & -1}, \quad u = \pmatrix{1\\0},
$$
if we stick to your requirement that "the alignment is zero if $u$ is orthogonal to any eigenvector of $V$", then the alignment $f(u,V)$ would have to be zero since $(0,1)^T$ is an eigenvector of $V$. On the other hand, $u$ is an eigenvector of $V$, so if the goal is to measure "how close a given vector $u$ is to being an eigenvector of $V$", then we have clearly failed to do so.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've thought better of my question, which was quite ill-posed, but I will leave it open and accept your answer to [avoid deleting it](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question).

Comment: @smalldog You're welcome, and thanks for that. That said, measuring "how close a given eigenvector $u$ is to being an eigenvector of $V$" seems like a reasonable thing to do. If you posted a new question that's more specific about how you intend to use this metric, perhaps someone could come up with a more useful metric.